# Applying rotation, location and scale to model bones

Tags: python, animation, armature, bones

I'm not an expert in 3D but I'm using Blender to change model's poses. I have a JSON object which describes how each bone will rotate, translate and scale:

```
{
  "name": "Soldier",
  "id": "TestId",
  "animMatrices": [
    {
      "name": "mixamorig:Spine",
      "position": [
        0.0,
        0.288420439,
        -0.027956875
      ],
      "rotation": [
        -0.0205147546,
        0.0105156591,
        0.0171466451,
        0.9995872
      ],
      "scale": [
        1.0,
        1.00000012,
        1.00000024
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "mixamorig:Spine1",
      "position": [
        0.0,
        0.338067949,
        5.486072E-9
      ],
      "rotation": [
        0.0558569357,
        0.0207238179,
        0.0163610559,
        0.9980896
      ],
      "scale": [
        1.0,
        1.00000012,
        1.00000024
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to generate the 4x4 matrix and assign it to `bone.matrix_basis` as following:

```
pos = mathutils.Matrix.Translation((m['position'][0],m['position'][1], m['position'][2]))

rot1 = mathutils.Matrix.Rotation(math.radians(m['rotation'][0]), 4, 'X')
rot2 = mathutils.Matrix.Rotation(math.radians(m['rotation'][1]), 4, 'Y')
rot3 = mathutils.Matrix.Rotation(math.radians(m['rotation'][2]), 4, 'Z')
rot = rot1 * rot2 * rot3

scale1 = mathutils.Matrix.Scale(m['scale'][0], 4)
scale2 = mathutils.Matrix.Scale(m['scale'][1], 4)
scale3 = mathutils.Matrix.Scale(m['scale'][2], 4)
scale = scale1 * scale2 * scale3

bon_mat = pos * rot * scale
bone.matrix_basis = bon_mat
```

The model started to be having a very incorrect values, or I don't really know what happened.

I tried to to use `bone.rotation_axis_angle` but this did not effect anything, and by the way I always set:

```
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="POSE")
```

and I got the JSON object from Unity.

Comment: there is a great examples of armature posing [in the doc see this page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:IT/2.5/Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets/Armatures)

Answer (score 1):

You need the position for only loose bones. Instead of creating matrices assign the data where it belongs.

```
import bpy
if bpy.context.active_object.mode != 'POSE':
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set('POSE')

pbones = bpy.context.active_object.pose.bones

pbones['Spine'].location = m['position']
pbones['Spine'].scale = m['scale']

# I think your rotations are in quaternions, they are 4D
pbones['Spine'].rotation_quaternion = m['rotation']

# If not and you only use the first 3 values then:
#pbones['Spine'].rotation_mode = 'XYZ'
#pbones['Spine'].rotation_euler = m['rotation'][:3]
```

You can sure do this also by building the matrices, but check what your rotation data is in. You are building the rot_mat from Euler but I suspect your data being as quaternions.

Comment: I tried to do this but the model did not move at all, do I have to update the scene or do anything?

Comment: @AlQurashi there should be no need to update but it doesn't hurt. The code above works with this testing dictionary: `m = {}
m['position'] = [0.0, 0.288420439, -0.027956875]
m['rotation'] = [-0.0205147546, 0.0105156591, 0.0171466451, 0.9995872]
m['scale'] = [1.0, 1.00000012, 1.00000024]`

Comment: Ok, now I get it and its changing, The problem is I get these values out from Unity, when I change these values, the models is damaged, what can I do?

Comment: @AlQurashi You should probably also validate the data getting out of unity. If they are in bone space or global space, left/right hand system, check the rotation values if they are correct and also check if or how were the bones transformed on import to blender.